# Let $2^x=3x$. Show that the equation has a solution in the range $(0, 1).$

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Let $2^x=3x$. Show that the equation has a solution in the range $(0, 1).$

I was trying to apply just Bolzano's theorem here, but seems that that's not quite enough?

Denoting $f(x) = 2^x-3x$ and differentiating one has $f'(x) = 2^{x-1}x -3$ and then picking for example $x=\frac32$ I have $f'(\frac{3}{2})=\frac{3\cdot \:2^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2}-3 <0$ and $x=\frac{1}{2}$ I have $f'(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}-3<0$ which are both unfortunately negative...

Looking at the graph of the derivative it seems that it's negative everywhere in $(0,1).$ I guess I just have to use limit definition or something here?

Comment: Have you tried using the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: Ah indeed. Thanks...

Comment: The derivative of $2^x$ is NOT $2^{x-1}x$, it's $2^x \log 2$

Answer (score 2):

$$ f= 2^x - 3x$$

$$ f(1) = -1$$

$$ f(0) = 1$$

By intermediate value theorem ,we have the required statement. QED